# how can I plot a complex data structure

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data way much bigger than this representative one

```
df<- structure(list(Pama1 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("", "DD1", "n/a", "PAMANA", "zf"), class = "factor"), 
    X = structure(c(11L, 3L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "116", "12", "138", "197", "219", "224", 
    "230", "280", "85", "Start1"), class = "factor"), X.1 = structure(c(11L, 
    10L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "101", "145", "199", "222", "227", "233", "238", "331", "89", 
    "End1"), class = "factor"), Pama2 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "DD2", "GGTR", 
    "n/a", "PAMANA", "T_reg"), class = "factor"), X.2 = structure(c(9L, 
    2L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", 
    "115", "208", "214", "232", "376", "85", "Start2"), class = "factor"), 
    X.3 = structure(c(10L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "15", "195", "229", "231", "362", "577", 
    "76", "86", "End2"), class = "factor"), Pama3 = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("DD3", 
    "GGTR", "n/a"), class = "factor"), X.4 = structure(c(10L, 
    1L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", 
    "129", "136", "153", "166", "178", "48", "65", "66", "Start1"
    ), class = "factor"), X.5 = structure(c(10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
    3L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("131", "138", "144", 
    "168", "180", "34", "51", "70", "79", "End2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Pama1", 
"X", "X.1", "Pama2", "X.2", "X.3", "Pama3", "X.4", "X.5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

At first I put all starts and ends together and find the range

In this example it is 1 to 577

Then I want to plot or highlight the regions that there is a string

for example, something like this figure that I made

[image]

**or even like this**

[image]

Comment: It's really not very clear what you're asking for here. What do you mean by a "string"? All of these are Factors.

Comment: @RobertMc  string means whatever except n/a in columns DD1, DD2, DD3 etc etc

Comment: I am guessing that these are domains in protein sequences? So this link may help: http://dozenoaks.ghost.io/ggplot2-to-plot-proteins/

Comment: @neilfws what is the domain of protein?

Comment: @nik So then the first step would be to actually transform "n/a" to `NA`, since that's not the same thing. Try this: `df <- purrr::map_df(df, function(y) gsub("n/a", NA, y))` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below tidies up the data into a form suitable for plotting and then uses `geom_segment` to lay out the sequences. To tidy the data, we want each column to be a variable and each row to be an observation.

```
library(tidyverse)

## Clean up data frame and convert to long form
df = map_df(seq(1,ncol(df),3),                                    # Turn each group of three columns into separate data frames that we'll stack into long format
            ~ setNames(df[-1,.x:(.x+2)], c("DD","Start","End")),  # Column names appear to be in the first data row, so we'll remove this row and provide new column names
            .id="Pama") %>%                                       # This line and next add a "Pama" column
  mutate(Pama = paste0("Pama", Pama)) %>%
  filter(!DD %in% c("n/a","")) %>%                                # Remove empty rows
  mutate_at(vars(matches("^[SE]")), funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))  # All columns are in character format. Convert the numbers to numeric format.
```

The data frame now looks like this:

> ```
>    Pama     DD Start   End
>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 Pama1     zf    12    89
> 2 Pama1     zf   116   199
> 3 Pama1 PAMANA   280   331
> 4 Pama2   GGTR   115   195
> 5 Pama2  T_reg   232   362
> 6 Pama2 PAMANA   376   577
> 7 Pama3   GGTR    66   144
> ```

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=Pama, yend=Pama)) +
  geom_segment(data=data.frame(Pama=unique(df$Pama), x=min(df$Start), xend=max(df$End)),
               aes(x=x, xend=xend), colour="grey80", size=10) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Start, xend=End, colour=DD), size=20) +
  geom_text(aes(x=(Start+End)/2, label=DD), colour="white", size=3, fontface="bold") +
  geom_text(data=gather(df, key, value, Start:End), 
            aes(x=value, label=value, colour=DD), size=2.5, 
            fontface="bold", position=position_nudge(0,-0.3)) +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,100)) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  theme_classic(base_size=15) +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To address your comment, here's another way of positioning the numbers to avoid overlap.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=Pama, yend=Pama)) +
  geom_segment(data=data.frame(Pama=unique(df$Pama), x=min(df$Start), xend=max(df$End)),
               aes(x=x, xend=xend), colour="grey80", size=10) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Start, xend=End, colour=DD), size=20) +
  geom_text(aes(x=(Start+End)/2, label=DD), colour="white", size=3, fontface="bold") +
  geom_text(data=gather(df, key, value, Start:End), 
            aes(x=ifelse(key=="Start", value + 10, value - 10), label=value), 
                colour="white", size=2.8, fontface="bold", position=position_nudge(0,-0.2)) +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,100)) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  theme_classic(base_size=15) +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** To address your second comment, we'll add a grouping column that we'll use to alternate high and low number labels:

```
# Add grouping variable to alternate high and low labels
df = df %>% group_by(Pama) %>% arrange(Start) %>%
  mutate(hilow = rep(c("high","low"),nrow(df))[1:n()])

ggplot(df, aes(y=Pama, yend=Pama)) +
  geom_segment(data=data.frame(Pama=unique(df$Pama), x=min(df$Start), xend=max(df$End)),
               aes(x=x, xend=xend), colour="grey80", size=10) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=Start, xend=End, colour=DD), size=20) +
  geom_text(aes(x=(Start+End)/2, label=DD), colour="white", size=3, fontface="bold") +
  geom_text(data=gather(df, key, value, Start:End) %>% filter(hilow=="high"), 
                      aes(x=value, label=value, colour=DD), hjust=0.5,
                      size=3, fontface="bold", position=position_nudge(0,0.3)) +
  geom_text(data=gather(df, key, value, Start:End) %>% filter(hilow=="low"), 
            aes(x=value, label=value, colour=DD), hjust=0.5,
            size=3, fontface="bold", position=position_nudge(0,-0.3)) +
  guides(colour=FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1000,100)) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  theme_classic(base_size=15) +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is one weird data structure you have. This will probably work out better down the line if you can modify the source data in some way to obtain a tidy `dataframe` from the start, where each column is a single variable and each row is an observation.

We can wrangle the data to obtain such `dataframe` (this is in `base` R, you can arguably achieve the same in other ways, also using `dplyr` or `data.table`):

```
df2 <- rbind(setNames(cbind(rep('DD1', nrow(df) - 1), df[2:nrow(df), 1:3]), c('DD', 'Pama', 'Start', 'End')),
             setNames(cbind(rep('DD2', nrow(df) - 1), df[2:nrow(df), 4:6]), c('DD', 'Pama', 'Start', 'End')),
             setNames(cbind(rep('DD3', nrow(df) - 1), df[2:nrow(df), 7:9]), c('DD', 'Pama', 'Start', 'End'))
)

df2$Start <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$Start))
df2$End <- as.numeric(as.character(df2$End))
df2 <- df2[!df2$Pama %in% c('','n/a'), ]


df2
#>     DD   Pama Start End
#> 2  DD1     zf    12  89
#> 4  DD1     zf   116 199
#> 10 DD1 PAMANA   280 331
#> 51 DD2   GGTR   115 195
#> 81 DD2  T_reg   232 362
#> 91 DD2 PAMANA   376 577
#> 52 DD3   GGTR    66 144
```

This gives us a nice dataset, where we can map any `ggplot2`'s `aestethic` to a simple column:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(y = DD, color = Pama)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Start, xend = End, yend = DD), size = 10) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Start, x = Start), size = 2.5, nudge_y = -.15) +
  geom_text(aes(label = End, x = End), size = 2.5, nudge_y = -.15) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = 'right') +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

#### Update:

The text positioning can indeed cause problems, it does so in this example, where we had to reduce the text size to get it somewhat right.

Here is a solution, based on the `ggrepel` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(df2, aes(y = DD, color = Pama)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Start, xend = End, yend = DD), size = 10) +
  geom_text_repel(data = function(d) tidyr::gather(d, k, p, -DD, -Pama), aes(label = p, x = p), size = 5, nudge_y = -.15, segment.size = 0) +
  # geom_label_repel(aes(label = End, x = End), size = 5, nudge_y = -.15) +
  geom_text(aes(x = (Start + End) / 2, label = Pama), colour = "white", size = 2.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(position = 'right') +
  guides(color = FALSE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

(The text size is forcibly increased to show it does not overlap)

[image]

PS: Yea, this update makes it even more similar to @eipi10 answer.. it's a great answer, of course I'd steal from him :P